# Internet Explorer Cache data from Directory

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, browser-cache

I am working with visual Studio 2012 and Internet Explorer 11

A am doing an Application where the Logged User can change the original Picture.

The name of the picture I stored in the Database, so, the name of the old picture and the new picture is the same.

my problem is that when I replace de old picture with de New one, it still show the old picture... This picture does not exists any more.

I close the browser and open again, but the problem still exists...

This not append in Crome...

I think the image is still in the cache and it doesnt care the picture it finds in the PC Directory.

How can i solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to delete the cache via the Developer tools in IE? (F12)

Comment: I solved it via Internet Explorer Configuration... but, as it is a Web App, I need to delete the cache via Code.. thanks

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood the situation. I thought you meant just to test something. Perhaps you can use HttpCacheability if you return the image via an mvc controller or just for the entire page, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcacheability(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What are the response headers for the picture? Is your server instructing Internet Explorer to hold onto a cached copy of the image for a while?

Comment: Hi, I don not have a response header for the picture... I just save the picture on the hard disk, and then load it... as the name of the old file and the new file are the same, Internet Explorer shows the old file... I have to clean the cache somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Hold Ctrl and press F5 to bypass the browser cache on reloads.